# Nifi convert json to custom json using jolt script

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

I have json like

```html
{
  "error_message_1": "missing_field_1",
  "error_message_2": "missing_field_2",
  "error_message_3": "missing_field_3"
}
```

I want json to be formed as below

```html
{
"payloads":[
{
   "error_message_1": "missing_field_1",
   "error_message_2": "missing_field_2"
   "error_message_3": "missing_field_3"
}],
"timestamp":"$timestmap",
"source":"nifi"
}
```

please let me know the jolt script for this.

Answer (score 5):

Use this **jolt** spec:

we are creating **payloads** `array` and keeping all `error_message*` keys into payloads array.

```
[{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
        "error_message_1": "payloads[0].error_message_1",
        "error_message_2": "payloads[0].error_message_2",
        "error_message_3": "payloads[0].error_message_3"
    }
}, {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "timestamp":"$timestmap",
        "source":"nifi"
    }
}]
```

**Output:**

[image]

In addition if you want `timestamp` value for the **timestamp** key then use the below spec:

```
[{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
        "error_message_1": "payloads[0].error_message_1",
        "error_message_2": "payloads[0].error_message_2",
        "error_message_3": "payloads[0].error_message_3"
    }
}, {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "timestamp":"${now():format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')}",
        "source":"nifi"
    }
}]
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "payloads": [{
        "error_message_1": "missing_field_1",
        "error_message_2": "missing_field_2",
        "error_message_3": "missing_field_3"
    }],
    "source": "nifi",
    "timestamp": "2018-10-30 08:51:16.572"
}
```